# Embedding Stripe pricing table in react web app gives eslint error

Tags: reactjs, typescript, stripe-payments, eslint

The [Stripe docs](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/pricing-table#embed) have the following code snippet to add a `stripe-pricing-table` element:

```
import * as React from 'react';

// If using TypeScript, add the following snippet to your file as well.
declare global {
  namespace JSX {
    interface IntrinsicElements {
      'stripe-pricing-table': React.DetailedHTMLProps<React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLElement>, HTMLElement>;
    }
  }
}
```

However, I get the following eslint error: `ES2015 module syntax is preferred over namespaces`. Is there a way for to me resolve this error without resorting to `// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-namespace`?

Answer (score 0):

You can disable it in your entire project by adding that rule in the `.eslintrc` file.

```
rules: { 
    ...other existing rules,
    "@typescript-eslint/no-namespace": "off"
}
```

Comment: I'm looking for the "clean" way to resolve this error, presumably using the ES2015 module syntax the error suggests.